# Can not use firebase.messaging() function

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have a problem with FCM.I follow fcm's docs when i call firebase.messaging(), it's take error: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function.

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.usePublicVapidKey('BGWGPG6yoYAa9zLB9Rhd_ov3w6o3cgpE3zk0KczWhEzbe_zHAAzThhtH3Gtl1XnIyZWdwmB4bocHIW9US1hiJ4k');

Help me please ! Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground

#### Web App

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your config
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

let messaging = null;
try {
  if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey("Your Sender ID");
  }
} catch (e) {}
```

#### firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-messaging.js");

const messagingSenderId = "Your Sender ID";
firebase.initializeApp({ messagingSenderId });

try {
  if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  }
} catch (e) {}
```